# My callbacks are wrong - I am returning my response to my error object - Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am trying to learn `node` and understand how callbacks are working.  I am doing this by trying to use the `async` lib.  I am trying to hit my db with 2 separate calls and use the `async` lib to let me know when my object is ready to build.  Here is my `aysnc` code:

```
  async.parallel({
    one: function(callback) {
      getUser(id, callback);
    },
    two: function(callback) {
      getUserServices(id, callback);
    }
  }, function(err, results) {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err);
      new Error();
    }
    res.json(result);
  });
```

Here are what my functions look like where I am calling the db.  There are both basically the same function:

```
var getUser = function(id, callback) {
  var query = client.query('SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE USER_ID=$1', [id]);
  query.on('row', function(row, result) {
    result.addRow(row);
  });
  query.on('end', function(result) {
    callback(result);
  });
};
```

My code hits the `db` and returns the `user`, but when it goes back up to the `async` code the `user` is in the `err` object.  What am I doing wrong?  How do I properly set up callbacks?

Comment: change it to: callback(null, result);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed by damphat, your code should be

```
//additionally, handle errors 
query.on('error', function(err){
    callback(err) // The first argument to callback should be an error object
})

query.on('end', function(result){
    callback(null, result) //passing null error object
})
```